# Google Sheets API quota limitations

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a service that downloads my Google Sheets (around 500kb) document using the API via oAuth2.

It sometimes times out with no error messages from Google (>80 seconds) and I would like to know why could be causing this timeout.

Is it normal for Google Sheets API engine to take this long to respond? I also have noticed that even if I tried with a much smaller sized file (around 50kb) - it can still sometimes timeout.

I have done some research and there seems to be some sort of quota limitations for the free version of Google Apps: [Current limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)

Would using the Google Sheets API be using the "URL Fetch data received " covered in the document in which I would only have 50MB/day?

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.